# Netzke on RAILS 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, netzke

I am newbe here about Netzke..
I am trying to follow the installation process in the Netzke web
site http://www.netzke.org  and also from the git Netzke-core site..

I just download the EXT JS 4.0.2 zip file from Sencha, extract it  and try to symbolic link the ext JS code to `<railsdir>public/extjs` directory..
and with the rails 3.1, I try also to link it to `<railsdir>/app/assets/`
javascripts and also `<railsdir>/app/assets/stylesheets`..

But it still does not work, because it doesn't find the file `/extjs/resources/css/ext-all.css`..

Please can you help which path or directory to link the EXT JS code to?

Linking the /code/sencha/EXT-4.0.2a to public/extjs
, that what I have done, but no success..

Comment: I have just generated a new Rails 3.1 app, sym-linked Ext into public/extjs, and have no problem accessing it in development env like this: http://localhost:3000/extjs/resources/css/ext-all.css. Can you confirm this works for you?

Comment: Basically, to me it looks like Rails 3.1 didn't change anything in the way the assets get served from `public` - they are still directly accessible.

Comment: Hi Nomadcoder,

Thank you very much for your help..
In fact, the symb-link in Windows Shell, does not work.. I just copy the EXT libray under public/extjs, and I try to access the file.. And I can access the files and sencha example.

But, further more, it is very strange, I just follow exactly your tutorial, and still and I have  the error below : undefined methode 'model_name'??
Any idea?
PS. The model is defined and db:migrate is done..
Thanks for your help.
Brice.

Answer (score 1):

set config.assets.debug = false in environment/development.rb file
it will work with Netzke

Answer (score 0):

I'm just newbie for Netzke too. I think your problem with `model_name` method is that you Use `GridPanel` without a config model to it. You should do something like this:

```
<% netzke :some_component, :class_name => "Netzke::Basepack::GridPanel", :model => "YourModel" %>
```

It should work :)